# Emacs configuration and usage

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close

Emacs is one of several editors particularly suited to software development.  As such, many Emacs questions are a good and natural fit to Stack Overflow.  Specifically, topics such as

- Writing Emacs Lisp functions
- Language-specific programming modes
- Compilation mode
- Integration with version control tools

are all well-received here.

However, there's a substantial number of questions that don't really belong:

- Editing plain text or other non-programming files
- Changing standard configuration variables
- Finding commands and binding them to keystrokes
- Installing and using extensions

---

I've proposed edits to [the tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17901674) and [its excerpt](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17901675) to clarify my understanding of what's on topic and thus improve the guidance to those with questions.

I have voted to close some of the most obvious non-programming questions with

> Questions about *using* programs such as Emacs are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they are specific to programming modes; you may be able to get help on [Emacs](//emacs.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](//superuser.com).  If your question is about programming Emacs, then please [edit] to include a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the Lisp or C code you're having trouble with.

Am I doing the right thing here?  And should I trawl through [emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs) questions looking for more questions which don't belong?

Comment: The general advise is to fix things you find, don't go find things to fix.

Answer (score 5):

Voting to close off topic questions is *always* a good thing, so if you are so inclined to spend your close votes this way, go ahead. There's a daily limit to stop you from going haywire.

Generally though, there isn't much use in closing abandoned old low view questions with a specific tag. Generally, it's better for you to browse as normal and close / vote on the posts you find that way, naturally.

But as long as the individual moderation actions (like close votes) are proper, I don't think it's such a negative if you do this. Maybe stagger it though and limit yourself to a couple a day to avoid burning out or filling the close vote queue with old stuff.